# Getting a list of all available namespaces in an AppDomain

Tags: c#, dynamic, appdomain, .net-assembly

I need to 'scan' the active AppDomain for all loaded assemblies at run time and get a list of unique namespaces available in those assemblies, does .NET support that?

The code must execute during the run time, so that the code is dynamic.

I just started coding in C# , so I'm a bit unsure about where to get started, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you just started learning C#, save reflection and other advanced stuff for later. My opinion of course.

Comment: I have been working with c/c++ and assembly for the past 20 years, so I'm not a complete noob, gotta start somewhere :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a matter of fact I wrote some code that lets you do that a couple of days ago.

**Use this class**:

```
    public class NSScanner
    {
        public static List<Type> GetLoadedTypes(AppDomain appDomain)
        {
            return _getLoadedTypes(appDomain);
        }

        public static List<Type> GetPublicLoadedTypes(AppDomain appDomain)
        {
            return _getLoadedTypes(appDomain, true);
        }

        public static List<string> GetUniqueNamespaces(IEnumerable<Type> types)
        {
            var uniqueNamespaces = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

            Parallel.ForEach(types, type =>
            {
                if (!uniqueNamespaces.Contains(type.Namespace) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(type.Namespace))
                    uniqueNamespaces.Add(type.Namespace);
            });

            var sortedList = uniqueNamespaces.OrderBy(o => o).ToList();

            return sortedList;
        }


        private static List<Type> _getLoadedTypes(AppDomain appDomain, bool onlyPublicTypes = false)
        {
            var loadedAssemblies = appDomain.GetAssemblies();

            var loadedTypes = new List<Type>();

            Parallel.ForEach(loadedAssemblies, asm =>
            {
                Type[] asmTypes;
                if (onlyPublicTypes)
                    asmTypes = asm.GetExportedTypes();
                else
                    asmTypes = asm.GetTypes();

                loadedTypes.AddRange(asmTypes);
            });

            return loadedTypes;
        }
    }
```

**Usage**:

```
var publicLoadedTypes = NSScanner.GetPublicLoadedTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
var namespaces = NSScanner.GetUniqueNamespaces(publicLoadedTypes);
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 6):

Start from an [`AppDomain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx) (`AppDomain.CurrentDomain` perhaps) and call [`GetAssemblies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies.aspx). On each assembly iterate over the [types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) it defines, keeping track of which [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.namespace.aspx) each one is in.

As an example of how easy it is to do this with LINQ consider this:

```
var namespaces = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
                     .GetAssemblies()
                     .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
                     .Select(t => t.Namespace)
                     .Distinct()
                     // optionally .OrderBy(ns => ns) here to get sorted results
                     .ToList();
```